# Как настроить rsyslog и logstash для корректного отображения миллисекунд в метках времени в Kibana

Tags: linux, ubuntu, логирование, elasticsearch, rsyslog

Есть связка: сервис -> rsyslog -> logstash -> elasticsearch -> kibana.
Как настроить rsyslog и logstash, чтобы метки времени отображались с точностью до миллисекунд? Пробовал указывать в конфиге rsyslog для сервиса следующий шаблон:

```
if $programname == 'server' then {
 $EscapeControlCharactersOnReceive on
 # делаем свой шаблон вывода.
 $template CustomFormat, "%TIMESTAMP:fixed-width:23:date-rfc3339% %HOSTNAME% %syslogtag%%msg%\n"
 $ActionFileDefaultTemplate CustomDateTime
 action(type="omfile" file="/var/log/server/server.log")
 # send to ELK (tcp)
 *.* @@ip-address:514

stop
}
```

Настройки logstash:

```
    input {
        syslog {
            port => 514
            codec => multiline {
                pattern => "^<%{NUMBER}>"
                negate => true
                what => "previous"
            }
        }
    }
    output {
        elasticsearch { }
    }

    filter {
        if [type] == "syslog" {
            grok {
                match => { "message" => "%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:syslog_timestamp}         %{SYSLOGHOST:syslog_hostname} %{DATA:syslog_program}(?:\[%{POSINT:syslog_pid}\])?: %{GREEDYDATA:syslog_message}" }
                add_field => [ "received_at", "%{@timestamp}" ]
                add_field => [ "received_from", "%{host}" ]
            }
            syslog_pri { }
            date {
                match => [ "syslog_timestamp", "MMM  d HH:mm:ss", "MMM dd HH:mm:ss", "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS", "ISO8601" ]
            }
        }
    }
```

В файле:
Apr 23 19:04:21 2018-04-23T19:04:21.539 host server[5541]: message

В tcpdump'e при прослушивании порта 514:
<14>Apr 23 19:04:21 host server[5541]: message

Comment: похоже на то, что либо плагин `syslog`, либо плагин `codec => multiline` (которые в input-e) вносят свои правки. Я не использую у себя `syslog`, хотя все логи в logstash приходят от сислогов, и не использую мультилайн (по причине отсутствия надобности). Будет возможность - завтра погоняю тесты.

Answer (score 1):

Когда `logstash` получает на вход некое событие (строку лога), он сам инициализирует поле `@timestamp`, которое выглядит например так: 2017-12-01T11:11:39.051Z. Присутствует "миллисекундная" часть, при том, что приходящие логи могут эту часть не содержать вовсе.

По факту это означает следующее: в эластик попадет значение `timestamp` равное времени возникновения события на сервере logstash-а, а не на сервере, где это событие случилось изначально. Т.е. время rsyslog-а тут как бы вообще не причем.

В этом случае рекомендуют добавлять в лог (на хосте, где эти логи "производятся"), в его смысловую часть, дополнительно запись о времени события, а по приходу лога в `logstash` пасрить строку, доставать часть со временем, и помещать значение в поле, например, `event_timestamp`.

Согласен, что решение так себе, но более простое и элегантное видел только с `filebeat`-ом. Решалось все одной строчкой в его конфинге.

Comment: Проблема в том, что kibana выводит для каждого сообщения две разных метки времени:
 
     'at'timestamp = "2018-04-24 14:16:49.000" и timestamp = "Apr 24 14:16:49". 

Причем, 'at'timestamp всегда содержит нулевые миллисекунды, а timestamp вообще их не содержит.

Comment: @Alexey хм... у меня timestamp (в кибане) только от logstash-а, и выглядит он так (именно с миллисекундами) `April 24th 2018, 14:38:10.433`, никакого второго поля со временем нет. Время лога присутствует только в поле `message` где я храню лог целиком: `<22>Apr 24 14:41:22 log message`. В конфиге logstash-а много обработок входного лога? Может поля какие убираете/добавляете?

Comment: кстати, received_at как и received_from не появляются в kibane. received_at действительно не нужен.